# Outputting R forecasts to Excel

Tags: r, excel

I have started to use R to run forecast models as this is a lot better than Excel.  Especially the auto ARIMA model selection.  Is there a way of getting R to output the results of the forecast models to Excel automatically?

Comment: Depends on what the output of your model looks like, you can write a table/matrix to CSV or tab-separated

Comment: I find `library(rio)` to be great for both reading in and writing data to various sources. more information at https://github.com/leeper/rio. For example `export(mydata, file="C:/mydirectory/models.xlsx")` will automatically detect that you would like an excel worksheet as your output and call the appropriate functions for you.

Comment: You can write to Excel with the `write.csv` command, but don't forget to add `row.names = FALSE` (or write a wrapper `my_write.csv <- function(...) write.csv(..., row.names = FALSE)`). But then you still have to open this file, use text to columns and copy paste to another Excel file. If you want to open an Excel file and write value to certain cells, you should check out the `xlsx` package (never used it myself, so not totally sure it can do what you want).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm pretty new to R, so not fully up to speed on the commands.  I shall try all the above.. :-)